# How to declare & call NetShareEnum of svrapi.dll from c#

Tags: c#

I need to call the NetShareEnum of svrapi.dll (not netapi32.dll) from c#. What should be the method signature. It will be helpful if someone can help me with an example on how to call(parameters to be passed) it and process the result.

Thanks

Nishitha

Answer (score -1):

I believe NetShareEnum is located in Netapi32.dll?